# Encoding works fine on Linux, but not on Windows

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I'm writing an exporter in python that will get all the products from our database. Everything worked fine for me till I had to change my working environment from linux to windows.

So, our products have polish letters in them. Working on linux I didnt have to think about encoding when I was exporting data with pandas to csv. All the names, descriptions etc. had a proper spelling. But that changed when I tried my code on windows machine. After a little digging I found out that the problem shows up during sql query. Here is an example code:

```
import pymssql

server = "SERVER_IP"
user = "USER"
password = "PASSWORD"
database = "DATABASE"

try:
    conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, database)
except pymssql.OperationalError as err:
    print('Error!', err)
    exit(1)

query = """
    SELECT
        tw_Id as Id
        ,tw_Rodzaj as Rodzaj 
        ,tw_Nazwa as Nazwa
        ,tw_Opis as Opis
        ,tw_Symbol as sku
        ,tw_IdGrupa as Grupa

    FROM dbo.tw__Towar
    WHERE (tw_Zablokowany = 0 AND [tw_IdGrupa] in (2,5))
    """

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row)
conn.close()
```

The result of this code on linux:

```
(3, 1, 'Skuter Cristal BIAŁY 60V', '3 kołowy skuter elektryczny biały 60V', 'CRI-WHI', 2)
```

And here we've got the same code on windows:

```
(3, 1, 'Skuter Cristal BIA£Y 60V', '3 ko³owy skuter elektryczny bia³y 60V', 'CRI-WHI', 2)
```

I find it kinda strange but I tried looking further. Checked my ms sql database, found out that with

```
select name, collation_name
from sys.databases
```

That the collation_name for my database is Polish_CI_AS so naturaly I tried

```
conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, database, charset="Polish_CI_AS")
```

but with no result.

And now I kinda dont know what to do. I want to know why this problem shows up on windows but not on linux and how I can fix this.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Text is *text* so please post it as text/`text`.

Comment: drop Windows!!! ^_^

Comment: Are you querying the same instance and database in the 2 environments? If so, this looks like the problem is in the IDE/application enciding and *not* SQL Servers. If not, have you checked the actual values in the instance?

Comment: @Larnu Yes, same instance and database. I'm using visual studio code both on linux and widnows.

Comment: Hmm, I can't replicate the problem with pyodbc on Windows nor Ubuntu 20.04. Both give the same output as shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kTtB.png) with the exception of the file path.

Comment: I recently learnt that python on windows does not default to utf-8 encoding as it does on posix. Have you tried importing `locale` and then pass `charset=locale.getpreferredencoding()` to the `pymssql.connect` method?

Comment: @Larnu I just left work and I can't experiment on the computer where my problem occurs, but I will try tomorrow with pyodbc and look into IDE enconding.

Comment: @thisisalsomypassword i will definitely try this too!

Comment: @Larnu Changing from pymssql to pyodbc solved my problem on windows. Thank you very much. I'm still a bit surprised why pymssql works fine on linux but not on windows. The most important thing is that it works and I am happy about it :)